# The type '<>f__AnonymousType2`2[System.String,System.Int32]' must declare a default (parameterless) constructor

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq

I'm wondering if anyone here has an idea of why I'm getting the exception

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The type '<>f__AnonymousType2`2[System.String,System.Int32]' must declare a default (parameterless) constructor in order to be constructed during mapping.
```

thrown from my LINQ-to-SQL query

```
            var query =
                (
                    from change in context.ProductChangeTrackings
                    from expression in context.ProductDataQualityRuleExpressions
                    join rule in context.ProductDataQualityRules
                    on expression.ProductDataQualityRuleID equals rule.ProductDataQualityRuleID
                    where
                    (
                        from result in context.ProductDataQualityResults
                        where result.SKU == change.SKU
                        select result.ProductRowVersion
                    ).Any(rv => rv == change.RowVersion)
                    && rule.Status == "Active"
                    select new { change.SKU, rule.ProductDataQualityRuleID }
                );
```

I am running it through

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> ExecuteAsync<T>(IQueryable<T> query, CancellationToken token = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var cmd = (SqlCommand)this.GetCommand(query);

        if(cmd.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            await cmd.Connection.OpenAsync(token);
        }

        var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync(token);

        return this.Translate<T>(reader);
    }
```

and it throws on the `return` line.

Comment: I was looking for way to Translate to anonymous types too, but found no answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42406032/datacontext-translate-for-anonymous-types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your issue is with `Translate`. Create a class to hold your query results:

```
public class Result_SKU_QualityRule {
    public string SKU;
    public int ProductDataQualityRuleID;
}
```

Then use it in the query:

```
var query = (from change in context.ProductChangeTrackings
             ...
             select new Result_SKU_QualityRule { SKU = change.SKU, ProductDataQualityRuleID = rule.ProductDataQualityRuleID }
            );
```